# Azure Search: Index Document count does not correspond to Indexer document count

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

My web app relies on the Index "crconnector" on Azure Search. The index crconnector shows me a document count of 22 (see below).

[image: My Indexes]

However, the respective Indexer "crindexer" contains only 16 documents (see below).

[image: My Indexers]

Why does the Document count of the Index (22) not match the Doc Succeeded Count of it's respective Indexer (16/16)?
I already tried resetting + rerunning the indexer, which showed no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index can have documents in it for a number of reasons. Another indexer could have inserted documents, or the [add, update, or delete documents api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents) could have been used to insert documents.

Resetting the indexer does not delete documents. If you have a [data change detection policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-data-source#data-change-detection-policies) configured on your data source, resetting only removes the high water mark on the indexer so it re-indexes your entire data source.

In order to delete documents, you can add a [soft delete policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-data-source#data-deletion-detection-policies) to your data source. Note that you can't delete documents from your data source until your indexer has run again and picked up the deletes.

Comment: Is it possible to delete documents from the index without switching on soft delete on my azure blob storage?

Comment: Yes, just manually use the delete documents api. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents. Also, you can set metadata on the blob you want to delete combined with the soft delete policy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-data-source#data-deletion-detection-policies. For example, set the metadata field "isDeleted" = "1" on a blob combined with the soft delete policy, and the next time the indexer runs it will issue the delete api call itself